# Windows 10: Standard user logged in via RDP unable to gain admin privileges

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

Whenever I'm logged in to my Win 10 VM via RDP (yes, I could do so via virt-manager, but I don't want to have to put up with an emulated graphics card) and I need to do something with admin privileges, the usual way would be to invoke the function in question or launch a program with "Run as administrator", but the only thing that is happening is that the screen gets blued out, but the dialog prompting for the admin credentials never shows up. I have to kill this with Ctrl-Alt-Del and then click on "Cancel" to return to the desktop.
Whenever I log in via RDP as administrator I can invoke the operation in question, the screen gets blued out, and Windows prompts me whether or not I want to perform said operation.
If, however, I'm logging in locally (that is, via the virtual monitor provided by virt-manager) as standard user, I can invoke any admin tasks just fine, and the system correctly prompts me for admin credentials.
This again makes me wonder what is going on.

FYI: The Windows VM (Xen) is running Windows 10 Pro (22H2) with paravirtual drivers installed and part of an Active Directory domain. I'm also passing through an nVidia GPU.
However, being part of an AD domain and the PCI passthrough of the GPU can be ruled out, because the system had misbehaved this way before when it hadn't been part of a domain and without having the GPU passed through.

I'm connecting from a Linux VM (Xen) via RDP with Remmina as client.

The domain controller is another Linux VM (Xen) with Samba 4.18.8 as domain controller.

Comment: Normally in windows, you would RDP to the other computer and use the /admin switch to connect to the console session rather than a virtual one. That should make it feel like you are logged in locally. You can do this by connecting to the server, specifying the ipaddress and port, and adding /admin directly after. Eg: `12.34.56.78:3389 /admin`

Comment: The only problem is that I'm not RDPing to the Windows VM from another Windows box, but the connecting client is a Linux VM, and the man page of Remmina doesn't indicate the presence of any option to force admin privileges.

Comment: /admin is not forcing admin privileges, but forcing to connect to the admin or console port.

Comment: However, that still doesn't make it available under Linux so how would it help me?

Comment: This is a refresh problem. You should see what other RD client is available for your linux. RDesktop, or nomachine: https://downloads.nomachine.com/linux/?id=1